# Which of these means affection 愛情, 愛 or 情?

Tags: words, kanji, homophonic-kanji

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%84%9B#Japanese) says that's in Japanese kanji "愛" means "love" and "affection" however after checking on a [Translator](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E6%84%9B) in no case does "愛" mean "affection". Supposedly [愛情 is "affection"](https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/affection), the only difference being "情" added on the end. After realizing this I decided to check what "情" meant but I then found out that it also means [affection](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E6%83%85). How can a word have more than 1 kanji and how can a kanji share words. Also what is the correct kanji for "Affection"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

愛 is the "concept" of love. 愛情 is the physical emotion that humans feel. 「情」 be can added to other things in a similar way:

> [感情]{かんじょう} Emotion(s)
>
> [友情]{ゆうじょう} Friendship
>
> [情熱]{じょうねつ} Passion (lit. "emotional heat")
>
> （彼は）[情]{じょう}がない (He has) no compassion/sympathy for others.

See a pattern?

The broader issue for you here (which I've seen from some of your other posts as well) is that it seems you want a clean one-to-one mapping between English words and Japanese words/Kanji. It's very natural to want this, and we all feel your pain. Unfortunately that's not the way it works.

Words are just labels for ideas/concepts we have in our heads. Some words point to the same ideas, some single words point to multiple ideas. Sometimes we don't have a label for a concept that exists in another culture, and vise versa. It's something like this:

[image]

This is just how languages work. For now, just keep learning, and keep asking questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I understand what you are saying because English is the only language I know and I am very new to learning any others, also I see from what you wrote before that "情" always means "じょう" , at least I think thats the case or does "情" have other meanings?

Comment: Remember the difference between "meaning" and "reading". 情 is **read** as じょう, and its **meaning** has to do with emotions. じょう is the most common reading of that Kanji, and it's the only one you need to worry about right now.

Comment: but 情 is always "read" as じょう and always means something emotiomal?

Comment: Yeah, see my edit. You're safe to assume that.

Comment: Did you forget to post your edit?

Comment: I meant the edit I made to my comment here.